# A question about the order of pagination

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

Currently I'm deal with a history message page using Cakephp.And I got a problem about records' order.In the controller,codes about pagination as follows

```
$this->paginate['Msg'] = array('order'=>'Msg.created desc');
$msgs = $this->paginate('Msg');
$this->set('historymsgs',$msgs);
```

Then I got the first page which contains the latest messges like this:

```
tom:I'm eighteen.
Jerry:How old are you?
tom:Tom.
Jerry:what's your name?
tom:Hi nice to meet you too!
Jerry:Hello,nice to meet you!
```

But what I need is the reversed order of the messages.How can I append a condition of `Msg.created asc` here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: change `desc` to `asc` in your code?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel ...there're far more than one pages man,I need to show the lastest messages in the first page.

Comment: and so what? what's wrong with asc?

Comment: So the latest messages will be in the last page!

Comment: ok, ok got it. latest but in reverse order. well you have to find a way to reorder result set. if it was plain PHP I'd just use `rsort()`, but as it's not php but cake, you have to find a cake way. documentation probably would help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, in short, you want the first page to show the most recent history **but**, on each page, you want the messages to show in chronological order instead of reverse-chronological.

If so, you could try to use [Set::sort()](http://blogs.bigfish.tv/adam/2008/03/24/sorting-with-setsort-in-cakephp-12/) on the data set from each page.